# Is there a beautiful Symbol of \anchor?

Tags: symbols, anchor

I wish to find a beautiful Symbol of \anchor.

I can only find the anchor symbol in package dingbat, unfortunately, this anchor symbol is so ugly.

Has somewhere cute anchor?

Comment: use `\includegraphics` with any anchor you want?

Comment: Try \faAnchor from fontawesome.  It has many symbols which haven't been added to the "comprehensive" symbol list yet.

Comment: This is much better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an anchor symbol in `fontawesome` and `fontawesome5`, accessible with the command `\faAnchor` in both packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
From \texttt{fontawesome}: \faAnchor
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
From \texttt{fontawesome5}: \faAnchor
\end{document}
```